# m2eclipse - after pom and dependencies definition - no libraries on classpath / Maven Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, dependencies, classpath, m2eclipse

I've been doing just simple archetype projects until now, and always after dependencies definition and saving pom.xml, immediately after that the Maven Dependencies library was full of libraries. But now I declared:

parent(pom packaging, scm, repository management)

parent(pom packaging, shared dependencies)

actual project (jar packaging, few more dependencies)

actual project (jar packaging, few more dependencies)

---

I created them from the upper one by "Create module" ... Problem is, that I can't make it automatically fill the Maven Dependencies library

---

In .classpath file there is this line `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>` as in other "working" projects, but there is nothing on the classpath. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run `mvn dependency:tree` on the command line for the child project and confirm that you see the expected dependencies. If you don't, then there is something wrong with your poms (that you will have to post to get more help).

Comment: You're right. Dependency:tree shows only name of the child artifact. I was checking mvn help:effective-pom for the child artifacts that showed the entire dependency hierarchy. I declared <dependencyManagement> instead of <dependencies> for the parent project by mistake ... :-) could you please close this issue ? Thank you Pascal